# OpenCV imread function can not read image

Tags: c++, opencv

This code cannot read image. it compiles correctly, runs but can not load image.

```
int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

  if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
  {
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  namedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
  imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

  waitKey(0);
  cv::waitKey(50000);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about give the complete path of the image in your program. image = imread("/path/of/lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Comment: either what maythe4thbewithu suggested. or make sure you are running the application in the same directory the lena.jpg is.

Comment: I used both @Nadim Farhat & maythe4thbewithu tips. but not working. My os is windows 8 & compiler vc2013. Is there a problem working with imread with windows? However it worked by this:

IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg");

Mat image(img);

Comment: Add OpenCV bin folder to environmental path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are possibilities that these images are locked by some properties. Just use any tool like **snipping tool to make a copy of the original image** and try reading with imread. It will work for sure.

These kind of problems generally occur when you download the image from internet.

Comment: This method did solve the problem for me. I too faced the same problem when i was working with imread() function.